# input string is not in correct format for retrieveing gridview value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my grid view I want that when user click on activate then it navigate to activate.aspx page. And I want to retrieve three values from previous page to activate.aspx page. My code is:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
         {
         int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        Label1.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
        Label2.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        Label3.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into login values('" + Label1.Text + "','" + Label2.Text + "','" + Label3.Text + "')",con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
     }
    }

  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Redirect")
    {
        String email = "lblemail.Text";
        String mob = "lblmobno.Text";
        Server.Transfer("activate.aspx?RowIndex=" + email +mob, true);

    }
}
```

Aspx markup

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Larger" HeaderText="Activate/Delete"
                ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton1" runat="server" Text="Activate" CommandName="Redirect"
                        CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    <span onclick="return confirm('Are You sure want to Delete?')">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton2" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I'm getting error that input string is not in correct format for the following lines:

```
    int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
```

pls help me.

Comment: why are you passing email and mob as rowindex? what are the three values that you want to pass to activate.aspx besides email and mob?

Comment: what is the `Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]` in `int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);`

Comment: what is the value in `Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]` ?

Comment: he is passing emial + mob number as rowIndex

Comment: I am passing email and mob as row index because i want to retrieve them in next page i.e. activate.aspx.I want to store these values in database table named login which have three column username,pwd and mob_no. at the load event of activate.aspx

Comment: @DK007 how can you parse `email` to `Int` check your RowIndex value can you convert it to INT???

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are sending text/string inside RowIndex while as RowIndex i.e the index for accessing the Rows collection should be an integer.
What you pass into rowindex is 'lblemail.Textlblmobno.Text' and when you try to parse it into int it throws an obvious error.

Update: Ok, you don't need to pass the rowIndex.

First change:-

```
String email=lblEmail.Text;

String mob=lblMob.Text;
```

Second change:-

Rename the querystring parameters to more meaningfull names (i have done it in code below renamed rowIndex to email)

third change:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String email= Request.QueryString["email"];
    String mobNumber= Request.QueryString["mob"];
    String yourThirdParameter = Request.QueryString["thirdOne"]; // Provide your third parameter.

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into login values('" + email + "','" + mob + "','" + yourThirdParameter  + "')",con);
// Assuming this is the sequence.you can change it your way.

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

}


protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Redirect")
    {
        String email = lblemail.Text;
        String mob = lblmobno.Text;
        String thirdOne= // Fill it as is the need
        Server.Transfer("activate.aspx?email=" + email+"&mob=" +mob+"&thirdOne="+thirdOne, true);

    }
}
```

ALert:- As i suspect if you have to pass the Password as well then QueryString should not be used.
Also passing email , mobile numbers in QueryString is not advisable.

Comment: Answer is not worded correctly, "RowIndex should be int" What do you meant by this?

Comment: Can u please elaborate your answer with example.

Comment: how can I fix this error. Can u pls tell me with example. Pls help me

Comment: you need to pass email, mob and ? is it pssword. and what in the sequence of these in the sql command?

Comment: this code store lblemail.text, lblmobno.text into table instead of actual value.

Comment: do one thing place a breakpoint at the Server.Transfer(... line and then check what is there in the email and mob variables..

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (e.CommandName == "Redirect")
    {
        String email = "lblemail.Text";
        String mob = "lblmobno.Text";
        Server.Transfer("activate.aspx?RowIndex=" + email +mob, true);

    }
```

here you can see that you are sending email and mobile values as a querystring values so your query string would be looks like this

**activate.aspx?RowIndex=lblemail.Textlblmobno.Text**

and when you get rowindex value it will return ***lblemail.Textlblmobno.Text*** as a value debug it and watch it you will see it so now what you have to do is to just pass int value from gridview you are using

you can use hidden field also and find it from your **GridView1_RowCommand**

I hope this will help you regards...:)